# Java - How to alter a variable with its name as a String

Tags: java, variables, character

Okay, perhaps that was a little hard to understand.

I'm trying to count all the letters in a string and eventually print all the counts, and I'd like to know how to change the count of a character in my loop.

Currently it goes like this:

```
for (int i = 0; i<line.length();i++){
    line.charAt(i)++;
}
```

I have all the variable names as one character which they each represent, as in:
int a=0,b=0,c=0,d=0,e=0,f=0 etc

How do I use the ++ operator in this situation? **line.charAt(iter) gives me a character, but how do I use that character as a variable?**

Comment: If this is a Java question, then don't tag it as C#.

Comment: You need to increase the variable count, not the string. And I would suggest using [HashMap](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html) instead of variables.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

To do it correctly you should use a `Map`. Store all this letters in a map of type `Map<Character, Integer>`. Then you can update values like this:

```
// assumming your data looks like this:
Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('a', 0);
map.put('b', 0);
// etc..., you should probably init these in a loop


// then you can do
for (int i = 0; i<line.length();i++){
    map.compute(line.charAt(i), i -> i+1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could collect the counts using an `int` array.

```
int[] counts = new int[256];
for (int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++){
    counts[line.charAt(i)]++;
}
a = counts['a'];
b = counts['b'];
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're dealing with only lowercase letters, you can keep an array of counts for an old school "C style" approach:

```
int[] counts = new int[26];
```

then in your loop:

```
counts[line.charAt(i) - 'a']++;
```

---

Alternatively, there's the easier, 1-line way:

```
Map<Integer, Long> frequency = line.chars().boxed().collect(Collectors.groupingBy(i -> i, Collectors.counting()));
```

Where the key of the map is the integer value of the char.